# Running cmd in python

Tags: python, cmd

Atm I have this as my code, the first line seems to work well but the 2nd gives errrors.

```
os.chdir('C://Users/Alex/Dropbox/code stuff/test')
subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i test%d0.png output.avi')
```

Also when I try to run it as this, it gives a 1s cmd flicker and then nothing happens

```
os.system('ffmpeg -i test%d0.png output.avi')
```

Comment: At the top of the `commands` module is a big warning: *Deprecated since version 2.6: The `commands` module has been removed in Python 3. Use the `subprocess` module instead.* Heed it.

Comment: Use `os.chdir()` and `subprocess.check_output(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'image%d0.png', 'output.avi'])` instead, or use `subprocess.call()` if you are more in the exit code and / or do not need the command output at all.

Comment: Getting 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    subprocess.call('cd /Users/Alex')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified'

When I use call

Comment: Don't use `call` to change directories. Use `os.chdir()` instead.

Comment: `os.chdir('C://Users/Alex/Dropbox/code stuff/test/')
subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i image%d0.png output.avi')`

Still doesn't seem to work, I think that it forgets the dir it is in?

Comment: No, it doesn't forget such things. Something else is wrong for your case.

Comment: `os.chdir('C://Users/Alex/Dropbox/code stuff/')
os.system('ffmpeg -i image%d0.png output.avi')` this makes the cmd flicker on and off, but it doesn't do what it should.

Comment: and you are right, the dir is working so its the 2nd line thats broken.

Comment: I rolled back the question to its initial form, instead of the edited form which includes the correct usage (i.e. the answer below): thus making the question unclear.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For the later generations looking for the answer, this worked. (You have to separate the command by the spaces.)

```
import os
import subprocess
os.chdir('C://Users/Alex/')
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'picture%d0.png', 'output.avi'])
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'output.avi', '-t', '5', 'out.gif'])
```

Comment: what space are you talking about? Inside `subprocess.call()` is a list. I see no spaces inside the strings `' space where  ...   ?  '`

Comment: @PatrickT check the doc for subprocess.call, each list element is separated by a space in the final command.

Answer (score 10):

It is better to call `subprocess.call` in another way.

The preferred way is:

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'test%d0.png', 'output.avi'])
```

Alternatively:

```
subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i test%d0.png output.avi', shell=True)
```

You can find the reasons for this in the [manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments). I quote:

> args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence
>   of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally
>   preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required
>   escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file
>   names). If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see
>   below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed
>   without specifying any arguments.

Comment: I did the top thing and got back this error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Dropbox\code stuff\solarsystem.py", line 56, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'test%d0.png', 'output.avi'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

And it works in CMD

Comment: My guess would be that the location of the `ffmpeg` binary is not in the [system variable "PATH"](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm). Either use the full path to the ffmpeg binary in `subprocess.call`, or update the setting for Path.

Comment: ffmpeg is in system32, so it should be callable everywhere right?

Comment: Try `ffmpeg.exe` instead of `ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is old, but now there is an excellent wrapper for ffmpeg in Python : 
 `ffmpeg-python`. You will find it at https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

With it, the command could be achieved this way:

```
import ffmpeg
ffmpeg
    .input('test*.png', pattern_type='glob')
    .output('output.avi')
    .run()
```

Answer (score 3):

I also use subprocess but in another way.

As [@Roland Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16748593/5644303) claimed, the preferred method is (which isn't really comfortable):

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'test%d0.png', 'output.avi'])
```

The second method can be more comfortable to use but can have some problems:

```
subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i test%d0.png output.avi', shell=True)
```

Besides the fact that is [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) avoiding setting the shell parameter to "True", I had problems when the output folder contains round brackets, that is: "temp(5)/output.avi".

A more robust way is the following:

```py
import subprocess
import shlex

cmd = shlex.split('ffmpeg -i test%d0.png output.avi')
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

To know more about [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.split).
In particular, for shlex.split:

> Split the string s using shell-like syntax.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Python are you using? getstatusoutput() is deprecated since version 2.6. In Python 3 you can use subprocess for the same effect.

```
subprocess.getoutput('cd /Users/Alex/code/pics/')
```

Comment: I am using python 2.7, so I guess thats the problem :P

Comment: Getting `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getoutput` now

Comment: check out this page of documentation:  http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/subprocess.html